# Using AVAudioRecorder breaks audio on AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudiosession, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to record a audio/video session and simultaneously monitoring the audio levels.  I set up my `AVCaptureSession` Inputs

```
do { 
    try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
} catch {
    print("error adding video") 
}
audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
do { 
    let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
    captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
} catch { 
    print("error adding audio") 
}
```

That works.  But once I enable metering by adding the following

```
recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
```

...

```
audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
audioRecorder.delegate = self
audioRecorder.record()
audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
```

I loose the audio on the video recording.

I tried looking for the `CaptureDevice` from the `AudioRecorder`, but I can't find that, nor is the `isMeteringEnabled` availability from the `CaptureSession`.

Can anyone point me to the solution?

Comment: You don't need the audioRecorder. You can get both the video and audio from captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer. If you want the audio levels you can call averagePowerLevel in audioChannels.

Comment: I may be lost in these classes but even though the documentation says that AVCaptureFileOutput has delegate property for assigning the delegate with this protocol, but my Xcode tells me it does not.